# Qt5 QString and QPixmap

Tags: image, qt, label, qstring, qpixmap

My image does not appear :

```
QString champ("C:/champions/" + ui->comboBox->currentText() + "_1.jpg");
QPixmap image(champ);


ui->label_1->setPixmap(QPixmap(image));
```

I tried to solve this for 2 hours. Help me please ! Sorry if my english is bad because i'm french ^^ .

Comment: First check the content of 'champ' and check that it's a valid path. Then check that the pixmap could be loaded, by using QPixmap::load and checking the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qt QPixmap pointer limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876175/qt-qpixmap-pointer-limit/16876241#16876241)

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html#details

Like I mentioned in the answer above, use

```
bool retVal = QPixmap::load(champ);
```

Then check the retVal to see what happened.

```
if(retVal == false)
{
    qDebug() << "These are the supported formats:" 
             << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();
    if(QFile::exists(champ) == false)
    {
        qDebug() << "Unable to find file" << champ;
    }
}
```

Also make sure that your `QPixmap` isn't going out of scope. So put it as a member function in your header file.  Otherwise it may not exist at the end of your constructor.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html#exists

Hope that helps.